# reference variable inside python regex match

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have a simple python script to parse log files and if line matches defined pattern, extract the offending IP address.

Here is my sample pattern:

```
PATTERNS = [
'warning: Connection [a-zA-Z0-9_]+ limit exceeded: [0-9]+ from .*\[([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})\] for service smtp',
'NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from .*\[([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})\]: .* Relay access denied; .*',
'NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from .*\[([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})\]: .* Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table; .*'
]

PATTERNS_COMPILED = re.compile("^(?:" + "|".join(PATTERNS) + ")")
```

The problem is, the lines are too long. I would like to define the IP-matching regex outside and use it as variable inside my PATTERN match

If I define IP as:

```
IP = r'[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'
```

How can I then reference this inside my PATTERN expression ?
(I don't want to match the string `IP`. I want to match the value of variable IP)

Comment: Just FYI: If you need a full string match, you need to add `$` at the end of the pattern. You can only declare the `IP` variable and use it to define the patterns in `PATTERNS`. Python does not support subpattern recursion (like `\g<1>` in PCRE).

Comment: Is that clear or would you like a demo of what I mean?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew -  thanks a lot. A demo/example would be great.

Comment: Something like https://ideone.com/9RU5G6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by inserting the variable `IP` in the matching strings:

```
IP = r'[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'

PATTERNS = [                                  
'warning: Connection [a-zA-Z0-9_]+ limit exceeded: [0-9]+ from .*\[(' + IP + ')\] for service smtp',
'NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from .*\[(' + IP + ')\]: .* Relay access denied; .*',
'NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from .*\[(' + IP + ')\]: .* Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table; .*'
]
```